# Mint 15 Second monitor window sizing mess up

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, xrandr, display-settings

I'm running Mint 15 Cinnamon 64-bit on Dell Lattitude E6430 with external 24" Dell Monitor. The laptop has 1600x900 and the 24" has 1900x1080 resolution. I'm on standing desk with the 24" monitor configured ***on top*** of the laptop screen. Roughly like this:

```
_____________________________
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|        24"                 |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
------------------------------
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |     14" laptop     |
    |                    |
    |____________________|
```

However any app on the 24" monitor has issue with window sizing, maximising it put it on the edge of the screen either left or right side. It looks like it only figure out the max window size is the 320 pixels on the edge only like this:

```
_____________________________
|                        |   |
|                        | A |
|                        | P |
|        24"             | P |
|                        |   |
|                        |   |
|                        |   |
------------------------------
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |     14" laptop     |
    |                    |
    |____________________|
```

I hope that makes sense.

So how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem, solved by removing "Docky" dock from bottom to left side. :)

Comment: I'm on client side, so don't have that multiscreen setup. I'll give it a try when I'm back at office.